# Necessary to call close, logout when using with statement and imaplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

Is it necessary to call the `close` and `logout` methods on `imap4` class when using the `with` statement?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4) don't provide much context.

> Changed in version 3.5: Support for the with statement was added.

In the other, non-`with` [example](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example), they call both methods.

Do this?

```
with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP) as imap:
    # Do some stuff
    ...
    imap.close()
    imap.logout()
```

Or just this?

```
with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP) as imap:
    # Do some stuff
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IMAP4.__exit__` calls `logout`:

```
def __exit__(self, *args):  # from imaplib.py
    try:
        self.logout()
    except OSError:
        pass
```

So you only need to call close (outside the `with` block):

```
with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP) as imap:
    # Do some stuff
    imap.close()
```

Comment: That's strange. I wonder why they would only call one of the methods. The docs recommend calling close before logout. And, I'm not sure why I didn't just check the source myself, so thanks for not flaming me. Been coding for too many hours straight. :-/